# How to call phtml file in all pages Magento 1 Module?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to call `phtml` file in `all pages` in module in `magento 1`
Is their any way to can implement it?

Answer (score 0):

in your layout file you need to add the code like

```
<default>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" template="yourfile.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```